# Study in the Netherlands for an non-EU citizen who lives in another EU country

Tags: netherlands, eu-citizens

I am a non-EU citizen teenager who has been living in an EU country for almost five years.  I have come across this bachelor's degree course in another EU country that I really like. I want to apply for it, but as I am still a minor and I don't have my own residence permit, I am afraid that I will be considered as an international student and then I will have to apply for an entry visa again. Please, the country in question is the Netherlands.  I would appreciate it if someone can share their experience and knowledge of this issue with me.

Comment: You just need a new residence permit, not a new visa. It should be a straightforward process.

Comment: Would you move to The Netherlands, or would you commute from Belgium or Germany and study at a university near the border?

Comment: Yes I want to move to the Netherlands and study there because I already live in France.

Answer (score 1):

> therefore I am afraid that I will be considered as an international student and then I will have to apply for an entry visa again

If you are going to relocate to another country than the one you currently are a resident of, you **will** need a new residence permit, regardless of you having one in another country

The major exception would be if you do cross-border studying, but that is another can of worms